# How to clone Android source code via Git (getting Python "OSError")

Tags: android

```
computer@computer:~/android/froyo$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b froyo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/computer/bin/repo", line 685, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/computer/bin/repo", line 652, in main
    _Init(args)
  File "/home/computer/bin/repo", line 184, in _Init
    _CheckGitVersion()
  File "/home/computer/bin/repo", line 209, in _CheckGitVersion
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or direc
```

I am getting this error. How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't installed git. Make sure by typing `git` on your cmd prompt.

If there is a problem with your git installation, remove it by using

`apt-get remove git-core`

and re-install it using

`apt-get install git-core`